# python: catch exception for invalid JSON in requests library

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, exception, python-requests

I have pretty old system CentOS-7.4 and `python` package requests-2.26.0.

```
import requests
...

try:
   response = requests.post("http://localhost:8000", json={ '' })
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
   print e
except requests.exceptions.InvalidJSONError:
   print "Invalid JSON Error."
...
```

Since the `json` passed to `post` method is invalid, I was expecting that exceptions would catch it, however I'm getting this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./cfg.py", line 219, in <module>
    response = requests.post(URL, json={ '' })
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 117, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 528, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 466, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 319, in prepare
    self.prepare_body(data, files, json)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 471, in prepare_body
    body = complexjson.dumps(json, allow_nan=False)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 250, in dumps
    sort_keys=sort_keys, **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 207, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 184, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: set(['']) is not JSON serializable
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Requests uses `simplejson` or `json` libraries to encode the JSON data. Anything that raises `ValueError` is caught and cast to `InvalidJSONError`, but `TypeError` is not caught. [See here](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/b0e025ade7ed30ed53ab61f542779af7e024932e/requests/models.py#L472-L475):

> ```
> try:
>     body = complexjson.dumps(json, allow_nan=False)
> except ValueError as ve:
>     raise InvalidJSONError(ve, request=self)
> ```

Your test would work with either of these examples:

```
a = {}
a["a"] = a
requests.get("http://url", json=a)
```

```
requests.get("http://url", json={"a": float("nan")})
```

Easiest thing to do would be to catch `TypeError` as well in the `except`:

```
try:
    response = requests.post("http://localhost:8000", json={''})
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print(e)
except (requests.exceptions.InvalidJSONError, TypeError):
    print("Invalid JSON Error.")
```

Comment: A note I wont put in this answer.. It might be worth suggesting this upstream to `requests` as a feature enhancement and have them do the catch converting `TypeError` to `InvalidJSONError`

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. Is `TypeError` a python's built-in exception?

Comment: @Mark Yes it is! See here https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html